# Using a variable as a case condition in zsh

Tags: shell-script, zsh, quoting, wildcards, case

My question is the zsh equivalent of the question asked here: [How can I use a variable as a case condition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234264/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-case-condition?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) I would like to use a variable for the condition of a case statement in zsh. For example:

```zsh
input="foo"
pattern="(foo|bar)"

case $input in
$pattern)
    echo "you sent foo or bar"
;;
*)
    echo "foo or bar was not sent"
;;
esac
```

I would like to use the strings `foo` or `bar` and have the above code execute the `pattern` case condition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With this code saved to the file `first`,

```
pattern=fo*
input=foo
case $input in
$pattern)
   print T
   ;;
fo*)
   print NIL
   ;;
esac
```

under `-x` we may observe that the variable appears as a quoted value while the raw expression does not:

```
% zsh -x first
+first:1> pattern='fo*'
+first:2> input=foo
+first:3> case foo (fo\*)
+first:3> case foo (fo*)
+first:8> print NIL
NIL
```

That is, the variable is being treated as a literal string. If one spends enough time in `zshexpn(1)` one might be aware of the glob substitution flag

```
   ${~spec}
          Turn on the GLOB_SUBST option for the evaluation of spec; if the
          `~'  is  doubled,  turn  it  off.   When this option is set, the
          string resulting from the expansion will  be  interpreted  as  a
          pattern anywhere that is possible,
```

so if we modify `$pattern` to use that

```
pattern=fo*
input=foo
case $input in
$~pattern)                # !
   print T
   ;;
fo*)
   print NIL
   ;;
esac
```

we see instead

```
% zsh -x second
+second:1> pattern='fo*'
+second:2> input=foo
+second:3> case foo (fo*)
+second:5> print T
T
```

for your case the pattern must be quoted:

```
pattern='(foo|bar)'
input=foo
case $input in
$~pattern)
   print T
   ;;
*)
   print NIL
   ;;
esac
```