# Is there an "in" operator in bash/bourne?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bourne-shell

I’m looking for an “in” operator that works something like this:

```
if [ "$1" in ("cat","dog","mouse") ]; then
    echo "dollar 1 is either a cat or a dog or a mouse"
fi
```

It's obviously a much shorter statement compared to, say, using several "or" tests.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `case` ... `esac`

```
$ cat in.sh 
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in 
  "cat"|"dog"|"mouse")
    echo "dollar 1 is either a cat or a dog or a mouse"
  ;;
  *)
    echo "none of the above"
  ;;
esac
```

Ex.

```
$ ./in.sh dog
dollar 1 is either a cat or a dog or a mouse
$ ./in.sh hamster
none of the above
```

---

With `ksh`, `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob`, you could also use an extended glob pattern:

```
if [[ "$1" = @(cat|dog|mouse) ]]; then
  echo "dollar 1 is either a cat or a dog or a mouse"
else
  echo "none of the above"
fi
```

With `bash`, `ksh93` or `zsh`, you could also use a regular expression comparison:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^(cat|dog|mouse)$ ]]; then
  echo "dollar 1 is either a cat or a dog or a mouse"
else
  echo "none of the above"
fi
```

Comment: any reason for the double brackets? Thanks again!

Comment: @mrjayviper the double brackets are an extended test construct - AFAIK the regex operator `=~` isn't valid inside the POSIX single-bracket test

Comment: @steeldriver Only `[` is POSIX, but `[[` is extended feature of bash,  ksh ( apparently it's originated from there, and zsh.  `case` example is most POSIX of all, though

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Since at least bash 4.1-alpha there is no need to set extglog explicitly. [From bash changes](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES): *s.  Force extglob on temporarily when parsing the pattern argument to the == and != operators to the [[ command, for compatibility.*

Comment: @steeldriver The $1 in `case "$1" in` does not need to be quoted, no word splitting nor pathname expansion are performed in that token.

Comment: @Cyrus thanks for the regex catch - StéphaneChazelas thanks for the improvements, the extended glob in particular

Answer (score 11):

There is not an "in" test in bash, but there is a regex test (not in bourne):

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^(cat|dog|mouse)$ ]]; then
    echo "dollar 1 is either a cat or a dog or a mouse"
fi
```

And usually written using a variable (less problems with quoting):

```
regex='^(cat|dog|mouse)$'

if [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "dollar 1 is either a cat or a dog or a mouse"
fi
```

For an older Bourne shell you need to use a case match:

```
case $1 in
    cat|dog|mouse)   echo "dollar 1 is either a cat or a dog or a mouse";;
esac
```

Answer (score 8):

Using a `case` is fine and well if you have a fixed set of pets you want to match against. But it won't work if you need to build the pattern in runtime, as `case` doesn't interpret alternation from within expanded parameters.

This will match only the literal string `cat|dog|mouse`:

```
patt='cat|dog|mouse'
case $1 in 
        $patt) echo "$1 matches the case" ;; 
esac
```

You can, however, use a variable with the regular expression match. As long as the variable isn't quoted, any regex operators within it have their special meanings.

```
patt='cat|dog|mouse'
if [[ "$1" =~ ^($patt)$ ]]; then
        echo "$1 matches the pattern"
fi
```

You could also use associative arrays. Checking if a key exists in one is the closest thing to an `in` operator that Bash gives. Though the syntax is a bit ugly:

```
declare -A arr
arr[cat]=1
arr[dog]=1
arr[mouse]=1

if [ "${arr[$1]+x}" ]; then
        echo "$1 is in the array"
fi
```

([`${arr[$1]+x}` expands to `x` if `arr[$1]` is set, empty otherwise.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02))

Answer (score 6):

You *could* use a `case` statement in an `if` test, but the code would look a bit hairy:

```
if case "$1" in (cat|dog|mouse) true ;; (*) false; esac; then
    printf '"%s" is one of cat, dog or mouse\n' "$1"
else
    printf '"%s" is unknown\n' "$1"
fi
```

or slightly shorter,

```
if ! case "$1" in (cat|dog|mouse) false; esac; then
    printf '"%s" is one of cat, dog or mouse\n' "$1"
else
    printf '"%s" is unknown\n' "$1"
fi
```

This is using an `case` clause just to do the pattern matching for the `if` clause. It introduces an unnecessary true/false test.

It's better to just use `case`:

```
case "$1" in
    cat|dog|mouse)
        printf '"%s" is one of cat, dog or mouse\n' "$1"
        ;;
    *)
        printf '"%s" is unknown\n' "$1"
esac
```

---

Don't do this:

```
is_one_of () {
    eval "case $1 in ($2) return 0; esac"
    return 1
}

if is_one_of "$1" 'cat|dog|mouse'; then
    printf '"%s" is one of cat, dog or mouse\n' "$1"
else
    printf '"%s" is unknown\n' "$1"
fi
```

or this:

```
is_one_of () (
    word=$1
    shift
    IFS='|'
    eval "case $word in ($*) return 0; esac"
    return 1
)

if is_one_of "$1" cat dog mouse; then
    printf '"%s" is one of cat, dog or mouse\n' "$1"
else
    printf '"%s" is unknown\n' "$1"
fi
```

... because you're just adding more dangerous cruft, just to be able to use an `if` statement in your code in place of a perfectly reasonable `case` statement.

Comment: Wouldn't that be better to split case into function call and evaluate exit status inside the if statement?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy And let the pattern be an argument to the function? It would have to do an `eval` of the `case` statement in that case, and it would be even more prone to errors.

Comment: In this case there's simple pattern, each could be passed as positional parameter to function and do `"$1"|"$2"|"$3"`. Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234415/85039  But yeah, it's a bit hairy.

Answer (score 4):

`grep` approach.

```
if echo $1 | grep -qE "^(cat|dog|mouse)$"; then 
    echo "dollar 1 is either a cat or a dog or a mouse"
fi
```

- `-q` to avoid any output to screen (quicker to type than `>/dev/null`).
- `-E` for extended regular expressions `(cat|dog|mouse)` aspects needs this.
- `^(cat|dog|mouse)$` matches any lines starting (`^`) with cat, dog or mouse (`(cat|dog|mouse)`) followed by end of line (`$`)