# What is "in" in Bash?

Tags: bash, syntax

I have encountered this in the syntax for `case` after calling `help case` and getting `case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...) COMMANDS ;;]... esac`.

[There was a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447430/is-there-an-in-operator-in-bash-bourne), whether "in" is a bash operator, but answers were answering the script problem of the person rather than saying clearly whether there is or it is an operator at all. I tried to find it in [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.htm), but since *in* is a natural language preposition, the search provides lots of hits. Trying to find it as an operator, I was not successful.

Comment: In general you usually can get a good answer to "what is `foo` in Bash?" by invoking `type foo` in Bash (or `type -a foo` if you want). This works for many `foo`s, including `in`; try `type in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [reserved word](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reserved-Word-Index.html). From `man bash`:

> ```
> RESERVED WORDS
>        Reserved words are words that have a special meaning to the shell.  The
>        following words are recognized as reserved when unquoted and either the
>        first word of a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR below) or  the  third
>        word of a case or for command:
>
>        !  case   coproc   do  done elif else esac fi for function if in select
>        then until while { } time [[ ]]
> ```