# Bash, use case statement to check if the word is in the array

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete, case

I am writing a script which must accept a word from a limited predefined list as an argument. I also would like it to have completion. I'm storing list in a variable to avoid duplication between `complete` and `case`. So I've written this, completion does work, but `case` statement doesn't. Why? One can't just make case statement parameters out of variables?

```bash
declare -ar choices=('foo' 'bar' 'baz')
function do_work {
  case "$1" in 
    "${choices[*]}")
      echo 'yes!'
      ;;
    *)
      echo 'no!'
  esac
}
complete -W "${choices[*]}" do_work
```

Comment: Actually I was going to set IFS='|'. But it won't work anyway because `The ‘|’ is used to separate multiple patterns`, so it is not part of the pattern itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use a variable as a case condition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234264/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-case-condition)

Comment: They share a lot. But mine is more specific about arrays

Comment: Then please read my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list in `complete -W list` is interpreted as a `$IFS` delimited list, and it's the `$IFS` at the time of completion that is taken into account.

So if you have:

```
complete -W 'a b,c d' do_work
```

`do_work` completion will offer `a`, `b,c` and `d` when `$IFS` contains space and `a b`  and `c d` when `$IFS` contains `,` and not space.

So it's mostly broken by design. It also doesn't allow offering arbitrary strings as completions.

With these limitations, the best you can do is assume `$IFS` will never be modified (so will always contain space, tab and newline, characters that as a result can't be used in the  completion words), and do:

```
choices='foo bar baz'
do_work() {
  case "$1" in
    (*' '*) echo 'no!';;
    (*)
      case " $choices " in 
        (*" $1 "*) echo 'yes!';;
        (*) echo 'no!';;
      esac;;
  esac
}
complete -W "$choices" do_work
```

You could add a `readonly IFS` to make sure `$IFS` is never modified, but that's likely to break things especially considering that `bash` doesn't let you declare a local variable that has been declared readonly in a parent scope, so even functions that do `local IFS=,` would break.

As for the more generic question of how to check whether a string is found amongst the elements of an array, `bash` (contrary to zsh) doesn't have an operator for that but, you could easily implement it with a loop:

```
amongst() {
  local string needle="$1"
  shift
  for string do
    [[ $needle = "$string" ]] && return
  done
  false
}
```

And then:

```
do_work {
  if amongst "$1" "${choices[@]}"; then
    echo 'yes!'
  else
    echo 'no!'
  fi
}
```

The more appropriate structure to look-up strings is to use hash tables or associative arrays:

```
typeset -A choices=( [foo]=1 [bar]=1 [baz]=1 )
do_work() {
  if [[ -n ${choices[+$1]} ]]; then
    echo 'yes!'
  else
    echo 'no!'
  fi
}
complete -W "${!choices[*]}" do_work
```

Here with `"${!choices[*]}"` joining the keys of the associative array with whichever is the first character of `$IFS` at that point (or with no separator if it's set but empty).

Note that bash associative arrays can't have an empty key, so the empty string can't be one of the choices, but anyway `complete -W` wouldn't support that either and completing an empty strings is not very useful anyway except maybe for the completion listing showing the user it's one of the accepted values.

Comment: Argh, I forgot about `IFS`! Will it work if I set `IFS` to pattern-separator `|` and reset it to default after `case` statement? So `"${choices[*]}"` will expand to `foo|bar|baz` which seems to be valid `case`-pattern?

Comment: @vatosarmat No, in `case a in (a | b) ...` the `|` is not part of the pattern, it's syntax in the case statement. You could do something like `IFS='|' pattern="@(${choices[*]})"; shopt -s extglob; case $1 in ($pattern)...` (or the equivalent with regexps) but that means you can't have glob (or regexps if using `=~` instead of `=`/case) operators in your choices.

Comment: Your choice of `case " $choices " in (*" $1 "*) ....` only allows for exact match, a `$1` string of `foobar` will not be matched, only `foo` or `bar`. That is not the normal use of case statements and may cause (some) surprise to users.

Answer (score 3):

The values in the `case` statement have to be separated with explicit `|`, as the `|` is part of the syntax. However, as the values in the case statement must be a pattern, an extended pattern could be used.

Generate `string="*@($(IFS="|";echo "${choices[*]}"))*"` and use it as an extended pattern as in:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -ar choices=('foo' 'bar' 'baz')

string="*@($(IFS="|";echo "${choices[*]}"))*"    # value contains one option
#string="@($(IFS="|";echo "${choices[*]}"))"     # value is exactly one option

shopt -s extglob
function do_work {
  case "$1" in 
    $string)   echo 'yes!' ;;
    *)         echo 'no!'  ;;
  esac
}

complete -W "${choices[*]}" do_work
```

But that is changing the option of extglob, we can avoid that by returning it to whatever value it had when starting the script before exiting. Note that the value of `$string` is expanded at the time of function definition, not at the time when the function is executed. But a simpler solution is to avoid setting (and possibly unsetting that shell option by using the fact that the right side of an `=` inside a `[[...]]` test works **as if the extglob shell option were enabled** (no, sorry, that doesn't work in `[...]`). So, we can reduce the case expression to `[[ $1 = $string ]]` and (for echo commands) this works:

```
[[ $1 = $string ]] && echo 'yes!' || echo 'no!'
```

But, in general, it is better to use functions, and, as functions are not guaranteed to return an exit code of `0`, we actually should use:

```
if [[ $1 = $string ]]; then yesaction; else noaction; fi
```

As we are already solving the rough spots of this answer, we could as well make the completion able to use options with spaces as well. All that is needed is that the IFS splitting of options from `${complete_var}` has each option inside quotes and separated by spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a choices=('foo' 'foo bar' 'baz')

option_string="@($(printf -v var "%s|"       "${choices[@]}"; printf '%s' "${var%?}" ))"
complete_var="$(   printf -v var "'\"%s\"' " "${choices[@]}"; printf '%s' "${var%?}"  )"

#printf '%s\n' "${option_string}" "${complete_var}"

yesaction() { echo 'yes!'; }
noaction () { echo 'no!' ; }

do_work () {
    if    [[ $1 == $option_string ]]
    then  yesaction
    else  noaction
    fi    
}

complete -W "${complete_var}" do_work

return 34;
exit
```

That will set the values as fixed values inside the functions. No need to set `choices` to read only. And allows spaces inside the choices.

That is assuming that you will source (`.`) the script in your shell. Something like:

```
$ . ./script.sh
$ do_work <kbd>TAB</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>      # will show "foo" "bar" and "foo bar" as options.
```

The only glitch I can see is that the value of the completions will be presented inside double quotes: `"foo"`, for example. But that is not a problem needing solution IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `=~` operator for checking if a value is in an array.

```
if [[ " ${choices[*]} " =~ " ${1} " ]]; then
    echo "yes!";
else
    echo "no!";
fi
```

Comment: Note that `"${choices[*]}"` joins the elements with the first character of `$IFS` (which only happens to be space in the initial value of $IFS), so you'd rather need: `[[ "${IFS:0:1}${choices[*]}${IFS:0:1}" =  *"${IFS:0:1}$1${IFS:0:1}"* ]]`. Also beware that with the default value of `$IFS`, it would say `yes!` for $1 == "foo bar"

Comment: Using `[[ ... = *"$1"* ]]` is usually better than `[[ ... =~ "$1" ]]`, not only because it's more portable but also because most regexp libraries can't cope with non-text while bash's globs at least can (to some extent).