# Pattern matching using @(pattern)

Tags: bash

I would like to study some examples of pattern matching using `@(pattern)`.  Have not found actual examples after doing a search.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168769

Comment: Have seen only one example an using `@(pattern)` in the link provided: `@(foo|bar).txt`.  Was looking forward to scrutunise a greater variety of examples.

Comment: Question has still no answer as I do not see a list of examples using `@(pattern)` apart from `@(foo|bar).txt`.

Comment: What is the actual use for `@`?  I do not see it used, almost never.